# Headers are gone on FileStreamResult

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

The following method broke on me. The response headers disappeared on me. I can't figure out how those are set

```
[HttpGet("GetImproveIdeaAttachment")]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetImproveIdeaAttachment(string FileName)
{
    DownLoadContainer d = await _streamFileDownloadService.DownLoadFile(ImageStorageType.ImprovementIdeaAttachment, FileName);

    return new FileStreamResult(d.DownLoadStream, d.MimeType) { FileDownloadName = d.FileName };

    }
```

This is the only response.

```
 >>content-length: 0 
 >> date: Tue,25 Oct 2022 21:05:07 GMT 
 >> server: Kestrel
```

d.DownLoadStream is a memorystream. d.MimeType = "application/pdf", d.FileName = "5e7ce5f4-c9fa-428d-8783-a23e8d382fb4.pdf"

You can see the stream contents [image]

Answer (score 1):

In the process of entering this question. I noticed the `Position` on the `MemoryStream` was at the end. I posted to save someone the 2 hours that I just wasted.

```
    d.DownloadStream.Position = 0;
```